# Is there a Heroku webhook for Heroku Postgres credential rotation?

Tags: heroku, webhooks, credentials, heroku-postgres

I'm following the instructions in the [Heroku Postgres docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku) for creating an external application that connects to Heroku Postgres for its data layer. The instructions mention that the credentials are automatically rotated and I must handle this myself.

I read more docs to learn about webhooks existing to help notify the rest of your system that changes have happened in your Heroku services. This made sense to me to be an area where the Heroku devs would have implemented this. There must be a webhook that exists that I could use to be notified when the credential rotation happens. I found that there was the `api:addon` webhook which had the `update` event. I tested this webhook, expecting this to be what I was looking for, but I found that it was not fired upon credential rotation. It was only fired when I provisioned or deleted more Heroku Postgres add-ons.

Since the webhook I need doesn't exist, I coded a workaround where I expect a PostgreSQL library auth error to be thrown while my AWS Lambda executes. If an error is thrown, I assume it's from the rotation and I have the still running Lambda function fetch new credentials using the Heroku API and try the PostgreSQL query again, at which point it works unless there are other errors. I tested this while manually rotating my credentials and it worked okay, but it's kind of ugly code. See [here](https://github.com/welkie/serverless-managed-db-examples/blob/master/aws-lambda-heroku-postgres/handler.js) for a detailed example.

So at this point, I'm wondering if the webhook I'm looking for does exist and I just wasn't able to find it. Or, if it doesn't exist, I would like to request it as a new feature. I understand that the Heroku team may not want people picking their add-ons a la carte, and they want people to use the entire Heroku platform, but I think it would add a lot of value to the Heroku platform. Personally, I've enjoyed getting into more and more cloud services as I learn since I'm usually able to choose them a la carte. For example, AWS doesn't forbid me from only using S3 and nothing else from them. They do as much as they can to make it easy for me to link my applications to it, no matter what other cloud services I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Heroku directly to ask if this type of webhook existed and I received a useful response from them:

> There isn't a webhook specifically for credential rotations, although
>   with a bit of logic you can sort of recreate the same thing. Whenever
>   you Postgres credentials rotate, it will trigger a new release, which
>   does trigger a webhook. You can use that to inspect the release via
>   the API to determine if the values changed.